# JQuery banner rotator with fixed text overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I currently have a super simple JQuery banner slider within a website that works as I expected it to.

The only issue that I had hoped to have a text overlay over the slideshow, that stays fixed in position, while the images slide in and out behind it.

The code below is the entire web page, all JQuery is linked in externally.

The effect i'm after is:

[image]

Actually making the divs to hold the text is no problem, its getting it to actually sit over the slideshow and display permanently, at current its above the slideshow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Matt Salmon Film & Photography</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Offside' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollRight', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
                speed:    750, 
                timeout:  5000 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="headerWrapper">
      <div id="logo">
        <img src="Images/MattLogo.png">
      </div> <!-- End of logo -->
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">about me</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="projects.html">projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">contact me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div> <!-- End of headerWrapper -->
  </div> <!-- End of header -->
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="bannerCaption">
       Professional Photography & Film
       <div class="slideshow">
         <img src="Images/BannerPic2.png" width="1000" height="400" />
         <img src="Images/BannerPic1.png" width="1000" height="400" />
       </div> <!-- End of banner -->
    </div> <!-- End of bannerCaption -->
  </div> <!-- End of wrapper -->
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

CSS That relates to the slideshow:

```
.slideshow {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; float:left; }
.slideshow img { background-color: #eee; }

#bannerCaption
{
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: What do you have in style.css?

Comment: code formatting is your friend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change your markup a little bit and you need to do some more work on it as it is not great at the moment.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/heddix/MWewB/) (scroll right)

```
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    position:relative;
}
#bannerCaption {
    position: absolute;
    z-index:99;
    right:0;
    top:100px;
}
```

Comment: I came up with the same solution. Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zxuQ/) with the caption already formatted

Comment: After some tinkering, I had just about what you've suggested.
I was having trouble with the markup though, and your fiddle works with what i have!
Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS add

```
#bannerCaption{
    z-index:1;
}
```

And your text will be on top.